# How to tell the dimension of an argument function

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

Let's say I'm trying to write my own gradient operator function.

If I know the function is going to be $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, I could write

```
grad[f_Function] := { D[f[x,y],x] , D[f[x,y],y] }
```

But what if I want to make `grad` work for functions $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

I could do something like this:

```
grad[f_Function] := Module[{xargs = Table[Symbol["x"<>ToString[i]],{i,1,n}]},
    Table[D[f[xargs],xargs[[j]]], {j, 1, n}]
    ]
```

But then this only works with `f[{x1,x2,x3,x4}]` instead of `f[x1,x2,x3,x4]`. Moreover, how should `grad` know what `n` should be?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Alternatively, you can define an `Operator`

```
ClearAll[gradOp]
SetAttributes[gradOp, HoldAll]
gradOp[f_[x___]] := Through@Through[(Derivative @@@ IdentityMatrix[Length@{x}])@f][x]
gradOp@f[1, 2, 1, t] // TeXForm
```

> $ \left\{f^{(1,0,0,0)}(1,2,1,t),f^{(0,1,0,0)}(1,2,1,t),f^{(0,0,1,0)}(1,2,1,t),f^{(0,0,0,1)}(1,2,1,t)\right\} $

Or

```
ClearAll[gradOp2]
gradOp2 = Module[{vars = Array[\[FormalX], Length@#]}, 
    Through[Grad[#[[0]] @@ vars, vars][[;; , 0]][## & @@ #]]] &;

gradOp2@f[1, 2, s, t] // TeXForm
```

> $ \left\{f^{(1,0,0,0)}(1,2,s,t), f^{(0,1,0,0)}(1,2,s,t),f^{(0,0,1,0)}(1,2,s,t), f^{(0,0,0,1)}(1,2,s,t)\right\} $

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[gradF]
gradF = Grad[#, List @@ #] &;

gradF@f[ w, x, y, z]
```

> {(f^(1,0,0,0))[w,x,y,z], (f^(0,1,0,0))[w,x,y,z], (f^(0,0,1,0))[w,x,y,z], (f^(0,0,0,1))[w,x,y,z]}

```
TeXForm[%]
```

> $\left\{f^{(1,0,0,0)}(w,x,y,z),f^{(0,1,0,0)}(w,x,y,z),f^{(0,0,1,0)}
> (w,x,y,z),f^{(0,0,0,1)}(w,x,y,z)\right\} $

**Note:** In case you need it in other contexts, `arg` need be a `List`, for `Length[arg]` to work. For example,

```
Length[qwertyiop[u, v,  w, x, y, z]]
```

> 6

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
z = Array[x, 3];
D[f[z] /. List -> Sequence, #] & /@ z
```

Define your variables as x[1], x[2], ... (as many as you wish, and call them z). The first line uses the Array function to do this succinctly. Then apply the `D` function to f[z]. The `List->Sequence` solves the brackets issue (i.e., replaces f[{x1,x2,x3,x4}] with f[x1,x2,x3,x4]) and the use of map (the funny symbols `/@`) means it will be applied no matter how many variables there are.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
(* This method only works with functions with an explicit list of arguments,
     not with functions that use slots (#) *)
f = Function[{x, y, z}, x y z]; 

grad[funct_Function] := With[{
    n = Length[funct[[1]]] (* find the number of arguments*)
},
    Through[
      (
        (* construct the derivatives *)
        Derivative @@@ 
          Reverse @ Sort @ Permutations[Prepend[ConstantArray[0, n - 1], 1]]
      )[funct]
    ]   
];
```

Evaluate the gradient:

```
grad[f]
```

Apply the gradient to arguments:

```
Through[grad[f][1, 1, 2]]
```

If you want this version of grad to work with slots, you could try to look into the function and find the largest instance of `Slot[i_]` by using `Cases`. Obviously that doesn't work with `SlotSequence` (`##`):

```
f = Function[#1 + #3]
Max[Cases[f, Slot[i_Integer] :> i, \[Infinity]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For **explicit function arguments**, you can write it like this:

```
grad[f_[args__]] := Table[D[f[args], a], {a, {args}}]
```

This does exactly what you want. For example:

```
grad[f[x, y]]
(* {(f^(1,0))[x,y],(f^(0,1))[x,y]} *)
```

and

```
grad[f[x, y, z, w]]
(* {(f^(1,0,0,0))[x,y,z,w],(f^(0,1,0,0))[x,y,z,w],(f^(0,0,1,0))[x,y,z,w],(f^(0,0,0,1))[x,y,z,w]} *)
```

The trick is the `args__` pattern, which means that `args` becomes the `Sequence` of arguments, no matter how long it is (but there must be at least one argument). You can convert this `Sequence` into a `List` by writing `{args}`. This you can then use, e.g., in a `Table` the way I did. For completeness: the "dimension" of the argument function is `Length[{args}]`.

### Addendum

If you want a gradient **operator** instead, you could write

```
gradOp[f_[args__]] := With[{dim = Length[{args}]},
  Table[Derivative[Sequence@@UnitVector[dim, n]][f][args], {n, dim}]
]
```

such that

```
gradOp@f[12, y]
(* {(f^(1,0))[12,y],(f^(0,1))[12,y]} *)
```

You can even **make this operator work with pure functions**, as long as they don't contain a `SlotSequence`. First, make sure the above definition does not evaluate for pure function arguments, using `/;`.

```
ClearAll[gradOp];
gradOp[f_[args__]] := With[{dim = Length[{args}]},
   Table[Derivative[Sequence @@ UnitVector[dim, n]][f][args], {n, dim}]
] /; FreeQ[f[args], Slot[_] | SlotSequence[___]]
```

Then, define the case of a pure-function argument.

```
gradOp[f_Function] := Module[{C},
  (* extract all slot names in f *)
  With[{slots = Cases[f, Slot[i_] :> i, \[Infinity]]},
   (* replace the slots by variables *)
   With[{expr = f /. Thread[Thread[Slot[slots]] -> Thread[C[slots]]] /. Function -> Identity},
    (* construct a new pure function... *)
    Activate@Inactive[Function][
      (* ...which represents the gradient of f *)
      Table[D[expr, a], {a, Thread[C[slots]]}] /. Thread[Thread[C[slots]] -> Thread[Slot[slots]]]
    ]
   ]
  ]
] /; FreeQ[f, SlotSequence[___]]
```

With this `gradOp` works on both, explicit and pure functions.

```
gradOp@f[x]
(* {f'[x]} *)

gradOp[#1 - #2^2 &]
(* {1, -2 #2} & *)

gradOp[#1 - #2^2 &][x, y]
(* {1, -2 y} *)
```

It even keeps the slot names:

```
gradOp[Log[#xyz] + #test^2 &]
(* {1/#xyz, 2 #test}& *)
```